# Does Office 2000 work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

A friend of mine plans to buy a new **Windows 7 Home Premium** box and install **Office 2000** on top of it.

What can he expect?

Sadly, this information isn't even available in Microsoft's [Windows 7 Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?type=Software&s=%22outlook%202000%22&page=1).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Most Versions of Office's will always be made compatible with Microsoft's latest OS's..

Because Microsoft is providing long term support for office 2000

Comment: source :http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091011133129AAoGAq3

Comment: But Microsoft's extended support period for Office 2000 ended this summer: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifeoffice